# React Native with NativeWind styling landscape orientation: space-x not working

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

I'm trying to get up to speed with React Native & NativeWind but I seem to be having an  issue with the orientation modifier and device rotation.

I'm following a Udemy course, trying to build a demo app, and this is what I've got so far:

[image][image]

It mostly seems to work, however `landscape:space-x-8` does not appear to work.

I would like a gap between the image and text when in `landscape` orientation.

Here is the code:

```
const Splash = () => {
  const handleSignIn = () => {
    console.log('Sign in pressed');
  };

  return (
    <View className="flex flex-col">
      <View className="flex flex-col basis-2/3 items-center justify-center space-y-8 landscape:flex-row landscape:space-x-8">
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={require('@assets/splash_img.png')}
        />
        <View className="space-y-2">
          <Text className="text-center text-4xl font-bold text-zinc-900">
            You'll Find
          </Text>
          <Text className="text-center text-4xl font-bold text-amber-600 underline">
            All you need
          </Text>
          <Text className="text-center text-4xl font-bold text-zinc-900">
            Here!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View className="space-y-4 items-center justify-center">
        <Button
          title="Sign Up"
          size="lg"
          onPress={handleSignIn}
          className="w-3/4"
        />
        <Button
          title="Sign In"
          showBackground={false}
          size="lg"
          onPress={handleSignIn}
          className="w-3/4"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Am I misunderstanding how `flex` should work in landscape?

Comment: I think this space conditionally applies margin or right, with flex you can just use "gap" property. not sure what space should do, I never used before.